# Polymer custom element data input

Tags: html, polymer

I am building a basic folder system for a website. I have an array of folder names defined in $scope.folderNames. When I pass this array of folder names into my custom element, it converts the array of stings into one string. E.G. ["cat", "mouse", "dog"] becomes '["cat", "mouse", "dog"]' so that when I reference folderNames[0] it returns '[' instead of "cat". Any idea how I can prevent this from happening?

Jade element call:

```
folder-menu(id="folder-menu", angupoly="{selected:'$root.height'}", label="Folders", icon="folder", values='{{folderNames}}')
```

angupoly is a library that allows angular to use Node.bind() to listen to changes in custom element attributes.

Custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="/core-menu/core-submenu.html">
<link rel="import" href="/core-item/core-item.html">
<polymer-element name="folder-menu" attributes="label icon values selected">
  <template>
    <core-menu>
      <core-submenu icon="{{icon}}" label="{{label}}" selected="{{selected}}">
        <core-item label="hi"></core-item>
        <template repeat={{v in values}}>
          <core-item label="{{v}}">
          </core-item>
        </template>
      </core-submenu>
    </core-menu>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('folder-menu', {
      publish: {
        selected : {value:0, reflect : true},
        values : {value: [], reflect : true}
      },
      attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
        console.log(attrName, 'old: ' + oldVal, 'new: ', newVal);
        console.log(typeof(newVal));
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Console output:

```
selected old: null new:  0 
string 
values old: {{folderNames}} new:   
string 
values old:  new:  ["Calls","Flagged","Group1","Group2","Group3"] 
string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to watch out for:

- Polymer will [de]serialize array/object published properties if [their type is hinted](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attrhinting).
- properties which are an object or array are never reflected back to the attribute: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attrreflection. The `reflect: true` for `values` in your `publish` block doesn't do anything.
- `attributeChanged()` will always give you a string value (attributes are always strings). What you want is to observe the `values` property change in a change watcher (e.g. `valuesChanged()`). That will give you the object as expected (if you've hinted the type):

Here's te setup:

```
created: function() {
  this.values = []; // hint the type, and initialize in the element instance.
},
valuesChanged: function() {
  console.log(this.values, typeof(this.values));
}
```

http://jsbin.com/xizihana/1/edit